# Como evitar realizar un evento de javascript por cada autopostback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

Estoy realizando una aplicación en .net framework la cual tiene múltiples autopostback, y las validaciones de campos lo estoy realizando con javascript, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de realizar el evento click de javascript este se repite múltiples veces, el evento se repite la cantidad de autopostback que haya realizado la pagina, es decir que si en la pagina realice 3 autopostback el evento click de javascript de va a ejecutar 3 veces.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_guardar" runat="server" CssClass="boton" Text="Guardar" OnClick="btn_guardar_Click" />

<script defer>
    Sys.Application.add_load(() => {
        ...

        btn_guardar.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (txt_Val_A_Conciliar.value === '') {
                alert('No se ha declarado un valor a conciliar');
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            
            if (txt_Val_A_Conciliar.value !== valorNuevo.toString()) {
                valorNuevo = 0;
                alert('Los valores conciliados no son iguales al valor a conciliar');
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            
            panelProcesoAdministrativos.forEach(panelProcesoAdministrativo => {
                if (panelProcesoAdministrativo.value === '') {
                    alert('Existen campos vacios');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Pregunta 1 ¿porque utilizas validacion en js y no utilizas los webcontrol de validacion de webforms? Ejemplo [Walkthrough: Validating User Input in a Web Forms Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100)), Pregunta 2: Puedes ayudarte con una variable que cuando sea un "auto postback" la setees y que escribas en javascript para que no se ejecute dicho codigo.  ¿Esta puede ser una alternativa?

Comment: @JoseA.Fernandez lo que estoy intentando hacer es evitar las peticiones al servidor los autopostback, para evitar lo posible que la pagina se recarge, pero ya habia mucho codigo escrito para realizar el cambio a web metodos,